# Android Intent / Start Activity Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm having an Issue that I have two Activities A and B when I clicked on Button to change an Activity from A to B .  It Restart my Application I don't know what going wrong Please help me

```
public class Login_Choice_Activity extends AppCompatActivity{
   private Button d_btn,p_btn;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_login__choice);
       FindAllView();

       p_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

             //  startActivity(new 
       Intent(Login_Choice_Activity.this,Patient_SignIn_Activity.class));

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CLICKED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
   }
   private void FindAllView(){
       d_btn  = findViewById(R.id.choice_doctor_btn);
       p_btn  = findViewById(R.id.choice_patient_btn);
   }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcgAh.gif

Comment: Where is the code of going fro A to B ?

Comment: I comment that code
 startActivity(new Intent(Login_Choice_Activity.this,Patient_SignIn_Activity.class));

Comment: Can you post an exception. I thinks some exception occurs in 'Patient_SignIn_Activity'.

Comment: Are you trying to debuging?

Comment: Put Patient_SignIn_Activity code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be better if you create a method for opening the new Activity and call it from `onClick(View v)` method. Example

```
private void openActivity() {
  startActivity(new Intent(this,Patient_SignIn_Activity.class));
}
```

In your `onClick` call:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   openActivity()
}
```

Comment: I thinks it not relate to the question.